# How to tokenize using enum?

Tags: c#, enums, compiler-construction, token

I am creating a compiler. And currently working on tokenizer. I want to use some keywords that are already defined and want to use them as tokens. Is this correct method?

```
namespace TokenizerProjectCC
{
enum keyWords {batif, batloop, batshow };
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string token = keyWords + "1\n,ma(*)&^%$";
        string str = "batifme$";
        string[] tokens = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(str, token);

        foreach(string r in tokens )
        {
            Console.Write(r);
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis

Comment: I would use ANTLR - it generates C# source based on a grammar file. If it's for learning purposes, I would look at the ANTLR source code and see how they accomplished it.